# How to return function value to the main value

Tags: c, return

I want to return the id in the function check to the main function but the output is 0 even though I input another number

```
int check(int id) {
    int idd;

    printf("id : ");
    scanf("%d", &idd);

    return id;
}

int main(void){
    int id = 0;
    check(id);

    printf("%d", id);

    return 0;
}
//output : 0
```

Comment: `return id;` --> `return idd;` and `id = check(id);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the entered value from the function. Also, why do you pass a param to the function when you are not using it?

This should be

```
 int check( void ) 
 {
    int idd;

   printf("id : ");
   scanf("%d", &idd);

   return idd;  // <-- here you returned id!
}
```

Secondly you are not using the value returned in the main method. This should be

```
int main(void)
{
   int id = check();   // <-- here the value returned from check is now used

   printf("%d", id);

   return 0;
}
```